# Is There Any way to capture any update on the cloud firestore using Android app and then trigger the listen event in C# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, web-services, google-cloud-firestore

My team wants to use android UI with cloud firestore database. and some of our team are c# developers.
and we want to create an event to always trigger whenever there is changes in the cloud firestore database. Is there any way?

I want to trigger this method whenever the database was change.

```
  // [START fs_listen_document] sample event trigger c# using Google.Cloud.Firestore; 
                DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("test").Document("subtest");
                FirestoreChangeListener listener = docRef.Listen(snapshot =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Callback received document snapshot.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Document exists? {0}", snapshot.Exists);
                    if (snapshot.Exists)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Document data for {0} document:", snapshot.Id);
                        Dictionary<string, object> city = snapshot.ToDictionary();
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                        }
                    }
                });
                // [END fs_listen_document]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in client apps to simply trigger some code when anything happens in Firestore.  There are database query listeners, but those won't work the way you expect.  They are meant for monitoring the results of specific query results over time.

The provided way to receive events from Firestore is via [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions).  You can write backend code that will get triggered when a document changes that matches a pattern you provide.  You can then decide what to do with that. Perhaps you want to send a push notification to your client app if you think it would be interested in the update.